# Reloading Class on Select when add new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this JSFiddle:
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/5854/)

Code:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
```

as you can see i have added my selectpicker, which works fine, until you add a new line. I need a solution on how to get the selectpicker working once adding a new line.
I have tried adding the class again using jquery. but didn't work. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you will inspect your html then you will know that the rows that are being created with directives have additional html elements and select element has display:none style. While the newly added row does not have that additional html in it.

Comment: In order to make it work you have to add the additional elements as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call bootstrap picker each time you add elements

```
self.addGift = function() {
    self.gifts.push({
        name: "",
        price: ""
    });
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
      size: 4
    });//or $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

};
```